# When php returned entire form as json, then printed as html, the form is undefined when serialize()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

this is the scenario, I'm returning an entire form filled with values from php as json, then it will be fetched in jquery and appended to a div to display it.

So when I submit it using eg. (`$(#formID).serialize()`), it doesn't return any value, and didnt get serialized.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Sorry if its incomplete.

Here it goes:

from php:

i return values using

```
return json_encode( array( "msg"=>"test", "html"=>$this->getFormData()) );
```

"html" will return the encoded form which includes all the form fields.
"msg" will just return the serverside validation if any

from the client-side:

Im using jquery/ajax to post and return results like this.

```
                var _params = {};
                    _params["pageid"] = pageid; 
                    _params["page"] = page;                       
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        url: "control/route.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: _params,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                                        if (data.html)
                                        {                                            
                                            $("#formID").append(data.html);                                                
                                        }
                                        if (data.msg)
                                        {
                                            emp.message = data.msg;
                                            emp.showError();
                                            msg.show(200);
                                    }

                        });
```

this will render the result as a form with its values from the database.

But when Im gonna serialize the same formID, its not returning any value, do you think its because it was returned as JSON from php?

Comment: You really need to provide us with some more information such as the html markup, css styles and php script

Comment: you should publish some example of the json and the part where you're are trying to serialize and send the form.

Comment: what does `$this->getFormData()` look like in response? Look in browser console at the request to find out. If it is an array will need to parse it to html either at server or with jQuery

Comment: $this->getFormData() contains all the input fields and form controls with its values returned from database, its like a whole form with that will be inserted inside the formID.

Answer (score 1):

All `serialize()` does is encode a form into a URL-friendly text string for submission.  It doesn't automatically send off the form, etc. You're also forgetting to use apostrophes in your selector -- you're referencing an element's ID so you should use them:

```
$.post('/path/to/script.php', $('form#id').serialize(), function() {
  // Do something on success
});
```